# Как добавить перевод в массив

Tags: php

есть сайт на базе [levels-ranks-web](https://github.com/levelsranks/levels-ranks-web). На одной из страниц есть такие функции

```
function declension($digit,$expr,$onlyword=false)
{
    if(!is_array($expr)) $expr = array_filter(explode(' ', $expr));
    if(empty($expr[2])) $expr[2]=$expr[1];
    $i=preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/s','',$digit)%100;
    if($onlyword) $digit='';
    if($i>=5 && $i<=20) $res=$digit.' '.$expr[2];
    else
    {
        $i%=10;
        if($i==1) $res=$digit.' '.$expr[0];
        elseif($i>=2 && $i<=4) $res=$digit.' '.$expr[1];
        else $res=$digit.' '.$expr[2];
    }
    return trim($res);
}
function to_date ($date){
            $date1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
            $date2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
            $date1 = strtotime($date1); 
            $date2 = strtotime($date2);
            $check_time = $date2 - $date1;
            if($check_time <= 0){
                return false;
            }

            $days = floor($check_time/86400);
            $hours = floor(($check_time%86400)/3600);
            $minutes = floor(($check_time%3600)/60);
            $seconds = $check_time%60; 


            $str = '';
            if($days > 0) $str .= declension($days,array('день','дня','дней')).' ';
            if($hours > 0) $str .= declension($hours,array('час','часа','часов')).' ';
            if($minutes > 0) $str .= declension($minutes,array('минута','минуты','минут')).' ';
            if($seconds > 0) $str .= declension($seconds,array('секунда','секунды','секунд'));
            return $str;
}
```

Сайт поддерживает перевод на разные языки, но если я меняю

```
if($days > 0) $str .= declension($days,array('день','дня','дней')).' ';
```

на

```
if($days > 0) $str .= declension($days,array($Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Day'),$Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Days'),$Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Dayss'))).' ';
```

то почему-то не работает... Как сделать, чтоб работало?)

Comment: Покажите дамп `array($Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Day'),$Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Days'),$Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Dayss'))` пожалуйста

Comment: ээм... с php недавно начал работать, как это сделать?

Comment: Перед `if($days > 0) $str .= declension($days,array('день','дня','дней')).' ';` вставьте строку `var_dump(array($Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Day'),$Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Days'),$Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Dayss'))); die;`, сохраните и обновите страницу

Comment: Если выводит пустую страницу (скорее всего, с 500 кодом), значит нужно смотреть error log. Можете показать?

Comment: Если вставить внутри функции to_date(), то элементы для которых вызывается to_date() не добавляются в таблицу. Если вне функции. то выводит `array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "день" [1]=> string(6) "дня" [2]=> string(8) "дней" }`

Comment: Вы пытаетесь обратиться к переменной `$Translate` внутри функции `to_date()`, но внутри функции эта переменная не определена. Поэтому возникает ошибка.

Comment: Ну а можно к ней как-то обратиться из этой функции? Ошибки с логов приложить здесь не могу т.к. превышается количество допустимых символов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к переменной `$Translate` внутри функции `to_date()`, но внутри функции эта переменная не определена.

**Вариант 1**

Нужно добавить параметр в функцию:

```php
function to_date ($date, $Translate){
    $date1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
    $date1 = strtotime($date1); 
    $date2 = strtotime($date2);
    $check_time = $date2 - $date1;
    if($check_time <= 0){
        return false;
    }

    $days = floor($check_time/86400);
    $hours = floor(($check_time%86400)/3600);
    $minutes = floor(($check_time%3600)/60);
    $seconds = $check_time%60; 

    $str = '';
    if($days > 0) $str .= declension($days,array($Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Day'),$Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Days'),$Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Dayss'))).' ';
    if($hours > 0) $str .= declension($hours,array('час','часа','часов')).' '; // Аналогично
    if($minutes > 0) $str .= declension($minutes,array('минута','минуты','минут')).' '; // Аналогично
    if($seconds > 0) $str .= declension($seconds,array('секунда','секунды','секунд')); // Аналогично
    return $str;
}
```

Так же нужно найти все места, где вызывается функция `to_date` и передать в неё вторым параметром этот $Translate (не забывая, что в том контексте, где вызывается функция, эта переменная тоже должна быть)

**Вариант 2**

Сделать быстро, но **НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО** (***Настролько не правильно, что в порядочном обществе можно за такое получить по рукам железной линейкой***)

в `index.php` найти  `$Translate = new Translate;` и добавить перед этой строкой `global $Translate;`

Получится так

```php
// Создание экземпляра класса работающего с языками и переводами.
global $Translate;
$Translate      = new Translate;
```

и такую же строчку добавить в первой строке функции to_date:

```php
function to_date ($date){
    global $Translate;
    $date1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
    $date1 = strtotime($date1); 
    $date2 = strtotime($date2);
    $check_time = $date2 - $date1;
    if($check_time <= 0){
        return false;
    }

    $days = floor($check_time/86400);
    $hours = floor(($check_time%86400)/3600);
    $minutes = floor(($check_time%3600)/60);
    $seconds = $check_time%60; 

    $str = '';
    if($days > 0) $str .= declension($days,array($Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Day'),$Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Days'),$Translate->get_translate_module_phrase('module_page_vips','_Dayss'))).' ';
    if($hours > 0) $str .= declension($hours,array('час','часа','часов')).' '; // Аналогично
    if($minutes > 0) $str .= declension($minutes,array('минута','минуты','минут')).' '; // Аналогично
    if($seconds > 0) $str .= declension($seconds,array('секунда','секунды','секунд')); // Аналогично
    return $str;
}
```

**Повторяю, такой способ может вызвать ненависть программистов, которые столкнутся с этим кодом. Они могут знать ваш адрес!**

Comment: Ну я решил пойти правильным путём) Тем более to_date() вызывается только в одном месте у меня. С днями сработало, позже остальное сделаю. Спасибо огромное)